# How to generate UBL2.1 JSON file

Tags: json

We need to generate the JSON file in UBL2.1.
We do not have any experience on this before.
How can we do it?

Here is the sample JSON file we have:

```
{
"OrderType":"N",
    "HeaderData":{
    "CustomerNo":"3ZZC15",
    "OrderNo":"testing1234",
    "OrderDMY":"28022022"},
"OrderDetail":{
    "link_ord_data":[
        {"SKUNo":"3M-6445-SSP",
         "SKUQty":"15"},
        {"SKUNo":"9789810779078",
         "SKUQty":"145"},
        {"SKUNo":"ES-ENV-DL/U",
         "SKUQty":"50"}
    ]
   }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? How would a UBL2.1 JSON file look like instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mkrieger1 we had been required to provide a UBL2.1 JSON file, but due to we don't have any experience how the UBL2.1 JSON file, so we actually also not sure how UBL2.1 JSON should look like. so we hope that who have experience can share with us.